# issue with newline

Tags: line-breaking

i would like to return to a new line but it shows me this error :

```
! LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.
```

---

```
\begin{center}
{\huge {\fontfamily{pzc}\selectfont } Introduction générale }
\end{center}
 \newline
\begin{Large}

Un des problèmes qu’un chef d’une boite informatique peut rencontrer est la gestion du personnel, ainsi que la distribution des taches. En effet, il doit distribuer le travail a faire ou les fichiers a traiter manuellement. Ajoutant à cela, il ne dispose pas d’un moyen efficace pour la gestion des congés, le pointage et les pauses surtout pour les plus paresseux.
Pour automatiser ces taches, et rendre le travail plus fluide au sein de la boite, nous avons développé la solution « Darwin-ERP » dans le cadre de notre projet de fin d’étude. Notre application est un progiciel de gestion intégré (en anglais Entreprise Resource Planning) qui offre une optimisation d’efficacité, de temps et des services a travers une interface entre le client et l’administrateur d’un coté, et entre ce dernier et les opérateurs d’un autre coté.
```

Comment: `\mbox{} \newline`. But better is `\par\vspace{\baselineskip}`

Comment: problem resolved !

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 2):

```
\begin{center}
{\huge {\fontfamily{pzc}\selectfont } Introduction générale }
\end{center}
 \newline
```

After `\end{center}` TeX is already in vertical mode (between paragraphs) so the `\newline` is in error, simply delete it.

You also need to delete the `{}` around `\huge` otherwise the linespacing will be incorrect (it will be based on the normal font size) finally you need to remove the `{}` around the font setting, as it is the font is changed but restored at the `}` before it is used at all.

```
\begin{center}
\huge \fontfamily{pzc}\selectfont  Introduction générale 
\end{center}
```

Comment: thanks it worked for me ! another problem that i would like to apply the police size for the whole document but i don't khow how ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle “Police” is French for “font”, I'm surprised of you! `;-)`

Comment: @tarakammar you mean you want the whole document to be `\huge` ? just move `\huge` to outside the environment eg `\begin{document}\huge` but perhaps you are looking for a class designed for slides or posters that uses large fonts? simply changing the current font size will not change section headings etc.

Comment: i kept it with the value 12pt that's what i need thanks ^^